# Dynamic minimal polygons from intersections of other polygons

Tags: algorithm, geometry, topology

Let us have some polygons and polylines that intersect and thus create other polygons from their intersections. I am interested in the minimal ones like in the picture below:

[image]

Let's consider that the polygon that interests us is Polygon 1, because it contains point P in it. Now if the triangle moves, Polygon 1 will change, like in the picture:

[image]

As you can see, Polygon 1 now is a lot bigger and all other polygons have changed somehow (but I do not care about them). I can of course reuse the algorithm that computes all 6 polygons and select Polygon 1 by position of point P, but I am looking for a more clever solution, which would use some information of the components of Polygon 1 in the initial state to recompute it faster.

Comment: "Polygon 1" is not a polygon; one of its sides is part of a circle. Also, it's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @m69: You should not be bothered by the fact that one of his sides is a part of a circle. You can consider that the circle is transformed into a fine polygon that closely resembles it (just like it is done for drawing the circle, for example). I am trying to recompute Polygon 1 as fast as possible after changes in the system occur.